# All files are not printed

Tags: java, regex

I'm new to Java. I want to create Java code which gets the values into these folders:

```
/sys/devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp
/sys/devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zone1/temp
```

This is the code which is not working properly:

```
public static HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Double>> getTemp() throws IOException
{
    HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Double>> usageData = new HashMap<>();

    File directory = new File("/sys/devices/virtual/thermal");

    File[] fList = directory.listFiles();

    for (File file : fList)
    {
        if (file.isDirectory() && file.getName().startsWith("thermal_zone"))
        {
            File[] listFiles = file.listFiles();
            for (File file1 : listFiles)
            {
                if (file1.isFile() && file1.getName().startsWith("temp"))
                {
                    byte[] fileBytes = null;
                    if (file1.exists())
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            fileBytes = Files.readAllBytes(file1.toPath());
                        }
                        catch (AccessDeniedException e)
                        {
                        }

                        if (fileBytes.length > 0)
                        {
                            HashMap<String, Double> usageData2 = new HashMap<>();

                            String number = file1.getName().replaceAll("^[a-zA-Z]*", "");

                            usageData2.put(number, Double.parseDouble(new String(fileBytes)));

                            usageData.put("data", usageData2);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return usageData;
}
```

The end result is this:

```
{data={=80000.0}}
```

First problem that I found is that I get error when I use integer to store the value.
Second problem is that I get only one value. The output should be like this:

```
{data={0=80000.0}}
{data={1=80000.0}}
```

Can you help me to find the problem?

Comment: You can't insert two values into a *normal* map using the same key. This `usageData.put("data", usageData2);` replaces the value that was previously stored with the key `"data"`. You can use a [Multimap](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multimap) instead.

Comment: Try switching from `HashMap` to `ArrayList`.

Comment: About the second problem? Do you have idea why I get error when I try to use `usageData2.put(number, Integer.parseInt(new String(fileBytes)));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

file1 variable is actually the temp file. and since all the files named temp the following line will always result empty string "":

```
String number = file1.getName().replaceAll("^[a-zA-Z]*", "");
```

I believe that you want to use file variable which is thermal_zoneX. I also think the regular expression is wrong try the following "[^\d]", this will remove non-numerics:

```
String number = file.getName().replaceAll("[^\\d]", "");
```

As you can see here in the result and as I explained you have no key for the value because number string is always an empty string:

> {data={=80000.0}}

to get rid of the floating point try:

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Int>> usageData = new HashMap<>();
```

And keep using parse Double.

Comment: I get this result: `{_zone1={_zone1=73000.0}, _zone0={_zone0=61000.0}}`  For some reason I get also _zone which is not needed. Do you know how I can remove it?

Comment: then the problem now is with the regular expression

Comment: Thank you and one last question. Do you have any idea why I can't use Integer for this code: usageData2.put(number, Integer.parseInt(new String(fileBytes))); I get error java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "74000

Comment: @user1285928 Because this expression `^[a-zA-Z]*` matches every letter at the beginning of the string and "ends" if something else then a letter will be "reached". Therefore is skips everything behind the underscore: `"_zone0"`.

Comment: @Tom yes we solved this. Do you have some idea about the Integer problem described above?

Comment: You should try it now after we fixed the code. since before it tries to convert an empty string to int. which is not possible

Comment: I get `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "66000` when I changed the code to `usageData2.put(number, Integer.parseInt(new String(fileBytes)));`

Comment: What do you have now?

Comment: I get this `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "61000`

Comment: are you using parse double or parse int?? you should use parse double. but the hashmap value should be Int as in my answer.

Comment: It look to me that the value can be Integer. Why I can't use Integer everywhere?

Comment: the value format is double because it contain floating point. you must parse it as double using parse double. but then you can convert it to int by putting it in an int variable as I explained before.

Comment: can you include the exact content of the file in your question?